# google api library is not working in yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2, google-api-php-client

I was implementing "Register With Social Login Buttons". I downloaded the Google Client API library via **Composer**. I tested that outside the yii2 framework environment and everything is working absolutely fine and I have also received the user information.

When I put all the required libraries and my view file inside Yii2 framework's folder and tried to access that view file, It is showing me an error which is included below :

[image]

**Below is my folder structure in simple PHP**

[image]

**Here is my folder structure in Yii2 framework**

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please no pictures of code or errors

Comment: i dont think you have installed it in yii project you shuld open terminal and move to the project root `html/schoolmanagement/` and type in `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` and remove the `require "vendor/autoload.php"` from your view , your vendor libraries are loaded via yii in the entry script `web/index.php`

Answer (score -1):

As error says: no class found. Means autoloader is not working.

Your `require autoload` is wrong. Your Yii structure is different and vendor folder is 2 levels back.

Try use this path:

```
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: this is the wrong answer,  your vendor libraries are loaded by `YII` in the entry script `web/index.php` you don't load it in the views please delete the answer

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam And why you assume that OP *actually* has autoloader in index file?

Comment: there isn't any assumption, it is not set by the user but the `Yii Framework` one does not need to add it, the whole framework loads and runs on composer based on the autoloader call in `web/index.php` see [**`here`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/web/index.php)